# Best data structure for ordered list (performance)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have a critical section on my application that consists of taking a data source (unordered) and then execute an algorithm on each element in order. Actually I follow the next algorithm:

- Read the source and put it to a std::map, using the sorting element as key and the info as content.
- Read the map using an iterator and execute the algorithm.

I see that map may not be the best data structure, as I only need to add the data to a sorted list and then "burn" the list altogether (also, memory allocation is costly on mobile devices, so I'd prefer to do it myself).

I've done some research and I'm reading things like B-trees and Black-Red trees. They may be what I am searching for, but I'll ask here if anybody knows of a data structure that is convenient for that task.

In short, I want a structure with:

- fast insertion.
- fast iteration (from begin to end).
- everything else is not important (neither deletion nor search).

Also fast insertion is more important than fast iteration (my profiler said so :D).

Thank you everyone.

Comment: It might be worth adding a language tag to your question. A std::map is a red-black tree

Comment: If you think storing the data is costly, why don't you just process it as it comes in then throw it away?

Comment: @doctorlove: The input is unordered.

Comment: is the key value in a certain range?

Comment: @doctorlove I didn't include a C++ tag because my problem wasn't language-based. Today I'm implementing this in Objective-C++ but I'll need to port it to Android some day, and I may not be able to use C++ (I really hope I can).

Comment: @Atridas please answer fordperfect's question as if there is a specified range for the keys, you may be able to improve the algorithm asymptotically.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two efficient solutions:

1. Append elements to a vector; sort the vector; scan the vector.
2. Insert elements into a priority_queue; drain it.

The vector has the advantage of O(N) load time (vs. O(N log N) for the priority_queue). (Note that it still takes O(N log N) overall, due to the sort).

The priority_queue has the advantage of freeing memory as you drain it. This doesn't reduce the maximum memory footprint, and is probably of negligible benefit, but it's worth trying anyway.

Comment: Note that the vector method also takes O(N log N) : O(N) for *loading* the elements, but still O( N log N ) for sorting them.

Comment: @Boris: Thanks. I've clarified my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The theoretical better way to do this is to use [heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort).

However, in practice, the fastest way is to append your elements to a vector, and sort them using a quicksort.

In both case, it will take O( N * log(N) ) in average, but the quicksort has lowest constant factors.

Comment: Nonetheless, if it is critical to have efficiency, quicksort has that dreadful O(n^2) border case. I would suggest to use the vector, but for safety use mergesort instead of quicksort.

Comment: @cgledezma: This is indeed an important point, but in the end, it all boils down to the specific case and requirements of the OP and his/her definition of "efficiency". If the border cases are known not to happen, still use a vector quicksort. If it is OK to be slow from time to time, as long as is is -as efficient as possible- in most cases, then still use a vector quicksort. However, if you have no control over the input, and need to guarantee that is is always "efficient enough": use a vector mergesort (easy to implement), or a heapsort.

Comment: Hmm I may be misinterpreteing the question but it seems to me that elements may be added dynamically, meaning iteration and insertion need not be performed in the order you do them. In that case you will have to perform multiple sorts.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: this is not the way I interpreted the question: `I only need to add the data to a sorted list and then "burn" the list altogether`, so I felt the operation has to be done only once, after all the data is known. Otherwise, using a map or a priority queue is indeed a good approach.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but it is worth noting that after appending you shouldn't use sort using quicksort for a nearly sorted array, you should use insertion sort. C++'s `sort()` function almost certainly does insertion sort in the beginning or if the array is small, but if OP is writing all the code himself, it should be insertion. or possibly binary search of the ordered vector for insertion location.

Answer (score 2):

If your keys are in a limited range of values, you might want to consider the use of [Bucketsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). It is exactly what you ask for - a sorted list with `O(log(n))` insertion. It is also relatively easy to implement.

Comment: I wouldn't say so easy to implement, all the more compared to using `std::vector` and `qsort()`, already provided by C++ ;-) By the way, a `std::map` also has O(log(N)) insertion, and already provided in C++. To my knowledge, the only advantage of skip lists over `std::map`s is the ability to get the i-th element more efficiently, but it seems the OP only needs to iterate through all of them (no need to access independently the i-th element), hence doesn't bring anything useful over a `std::map`.